# Disable DNN logging to sitelog table

Tags: logging, dotnetnuke

I am trying to stop DNN from inserting records to the SiteLog table.

I have set the SiteLogHistory setting in the HostSettings table to 0 and DNN still logs visits to the SiteLog table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set the Setting at the Portal level.

Basically the Host Settings are for any NEW portals. As a super user go to Admin/Site Settings and you can find the setting there